# Which circuit simulator can be used in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation, 20.04, dependencies

I was searching quite a bit, but didn't find anything that would work. There is QUCS and a few other that work for older versions but some of the dependencies are not satisfied for newer OS platforms. I tried following threads that give a workaround for these dependencies but still... no luck.

If you know any new software that would work that would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`qucs-spice` is available as a snap. You can install it via the snap-store or with

```
snap install qucs-spice
```

Comment: Thank you mook765!